# From which api should i ask permissions?

Tags: java, android, api, permissions, android-permissions

Hey I am trying to ask for storage access permission and I notice that in my other phone which has android 5.0 the permission ask crashes the app. what should I do to ask permission without crashing the app in this android version and from which android version should I do it?

this is the code for asking permission:

```
  int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0;
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
    }

    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
    // app-defined int constant that should be quite unique

    return;
}
```

Comment: From API Level 23+

Comment: for all level you have to add permission in AndroidMenifest.xml file but for api >=6 you have to add extra permission in your code like you have done in your code. for binning of android development use library like https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions It can simple your work

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic permissions require API 23 or above, so you can wrap your code in a conditional checking the version of the API being ran.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0;
    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
        }

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
        // app-defined int constant that should be quite unique

        return;
    }
}
```